# Infamous Nexus 5x bootloop: why does heating or battery drainage allow it to boot?

Tags: boot-loop

I have been tinkering with my good old bootlooped Nexus 5x (how I wish there was an affordable Pixel these days!) and after naively thinking it had recovered spontaneously (it seems to have booted because drained battery?) I gave up on it. Then I saw it come to life again as it was bootlooping on top of a hot laptop. I now boot it at will by placing it on my espresso machine's cup warmer!

1. Why does this happen? What component needs to heat up in order
   for the system to work? Before the bootloop, why did it work at 
   'normal' operating temperatures? What changed after the bootloop?
2. Why would a drained battery also do the trick?

Comment: So, just to be clear, are you saying that "at present" your device boots normally only when warmed up, and goes into a bootloop without sufficient warmth?

Comment: @Firelord Yes, that is the behavior so far.

Answer (score 0):

you should try the 4core fix.

If you can boot your phone and enable oem unloock you are good to go.

Visit this post, there is everything you need.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/general/tool-bootloop-death-blod-workaround-t3819497

Hope it helped.

Manuel.

Comment: Can you describe in your answer the steps from the link in case it is no longer available?

Comment: Thanks; I don't know how to flash a ROM but might give it a try. My question was more electronics related, though.